# Angular7 does not display promise data, but if I hard refresh browser, it display

Tags: angular, promise, ngfor

This is my template

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articleList">
  <p class="title">{{article.title}}</p>
  <p class="content">{{article.content}}</p>
</div>
```

this is my ts code

```
export class IndexPageComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
}

articleList: any;
ngOnInit() {
  this.getArticles();
}
getArticles() {
  const query = new Query('Post');//sdk function
  query.find().then(res => {
    this.articleList = res;
    console.log(res);
  });
}
}
```

I really get response

[image]

template render nothing,but if I click hard refresh button of browser,
it render content.

I don't know the reason, is anybody can help me ?
My English not good,hope you don't mind.

This is the res[0]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a log to this question showing us the full content of `res[0]` please?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi yes,thank you for your response.

Comment: Are you sure, that query gets filled before calling _find_? It could be, that refrehsing the browser leads to getting data from cache whereas the first time you load it from your server, and the answer is not available in time (before _query.find_)

Comment: @schlonzo I have same opinion as yours, but I don't know how to solve that ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dataReady">
<div *ngFor="let article of articleList">
  <p class="title">{{article.title}}</p>
  <p class="content">{{article.content}}</p>
</div>
</ng-container>

export class IndexPageComponent implements OnInit {
dataReady = false;
constructor(private http:HttpClient, private cdr: ChangeDetectionRef) {
}

articleList: any;
ngOnInit() {
  this.getArticles();
}
getArticles() {
  const query = new Query('Post');//sdk function
  query.find().then(res => {
    this.articleList = res;
    this.dataReady = false;
    console.log(res);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  });
}
}
```

in the `component decorator` add this: `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Comment: This is unnecessary to be honest

Comment: You are welcome. If you need any help to understand why this way worked, feel free to ask. In most cases, anyway, is because the data would be rendered before the promoise has done its job. To answer Arif, maybe the OnPush is unnecessary, but the rest is not.

Comment: @WangJi when you have time, try to remove the OnPush to the decorator (or change `OnPush` with `Default`) and the code releated to the `ChangeDetectionRef`, it should work aswell.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi yes ,I replace OnPush using Default, it works as well. I should ask at here earlier, it block me about 4 hours.haha. I will spike the details of this solution, I will ask for your help when I have puzzles, thank you again, have a good day(or night, at least china is night. : )  )

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `async` pipe. `async` pipe will automatically get value from `Promise` or `Observable`.
But in your case you already handle `Promise` yourself.
So the `articleList` is not a `Promise` anymore.

Either remove async pipe from template:

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articleList">
  <p class="title">{{article.title}}</p>
  <p class="content">{{article.content}}</p>
</div>
```

Or set articleList to promise returned from query.find().

```
getArticles() {
  const query = new Query('Post');//sdk function
  this.articleList = query.find();
}
```

With your current code you should see in console error like this:

***ERROR
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '0,1,2,3,4,5,6' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'***

Comment: thanks for your response, I have removed the async pipe, but it is not work as well.

Comment: and I try to set this.articleList as a Promise, and I add the async pipe ,it still need me to hard refresh, haha, why angular like hard refresh.

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr? blitz?

Comment: Thank you dude~ it solved, I will write a blog for that after I learn knowledge enough. 
  :)

Answer (score 0):

"template render nothing" But when ? Do you have another functionality in the page that may save new articles ? Didn't you forget to add a call to `this.getArticles()` after saving those new articles ?

Comment: nop, articles saved on my cloud, and I didn't do anything else  in my codes :(